# try except inside a function - skip to end of function

Tags: python, api, try-except

I have a function that is on a schedule to run every minute. The first step is to pull data from an API. Sometimes this works and sometimes it times out. If it works, I want to do a bunch of stuff to the data and then save it. If it doesn't work, I just want to skip to the end of the function and not do anything. So here is how it works:

```
def job():
   try:
      a = requests.get("API address that sometimes work and sometimes doesn't")
   except:
      print('connection error')
   #a bunch of code that transforms the data and then saves it
```

and here is the scheduler:

```
schedule.every().minute.at(":01").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I can kind of achieve what I want by moving the `#a bunch of code` line into the try, but then other potential errors are going to be caught in the "connection error" as well.

Is there a way where I can make the exception skip to the end of the function? And then because its on a one minute scheduler it just tries again later?

I know its not reproducible code but this is simple enough that it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `return`.

```py
def job():
   try:
      a = requests.get("API address that sometimes work and sometimes doesn't")
   except:
      print('connection error')
      return
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple. oops